# how to use restrofit2.0 in this query

Tags: android

https://apitest.cn/1/classes/User?where={"mobilePhoneNumber":"888"}
This does not works:
@GET("User")
Observable getUserByPhone(@QueryMap Map params);

Comment: `@GET("User") Observable getUserByPhone(@Query("where") String jscon);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use Query Parameter of retrofit


@GET("User") Observable getUserByPhone(@Query("where") String jscon);
```